# what does TCPV4 connections established perfmon counter mean?

Tags: windows, tcpip, performance-counters

We have around 60 windows based SMTP servers behind a load balancer. Out of these one server is taking significantly less traffic (1/10th) when compared to remaining servers. From perfmon, I see high 'connections established' count for the server in question when compared to remaining servers (See attached image). Does that mean this server is taking less traffic due to Tcp connection exhaustion ?

[perfmon counters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFxRj.png)

Comment: `Does that mean this server is taking less traffic due to Tcp connection exhaustion ?` - It could be because of almost anything. What load balancer are you using? What are your load balancing rules?

Comment: It sounds like that server is responding slowly and can't handle the traffic.  Therefore, it is taking longer to process the connections it has while taking more connections.  This could be for numerous reasons.  I would start looking at CPU usage, network traffic, and io wait time.  Also, it could be that the physical host is slower and overloaded.

Comment: thanks Doug, that seems to be the problem. I will take another look at the server h\w .